# Is there a way to avoid a nesting of Flutter widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart, readability

I am going to try Flutter, but all examples on GitHub I've found includes code with a high nesting level of widgets that is bad for readability. For example, this one:
https://github.com/smartherd/Flutter-Demos/blob/master/lib/screens/note_list.dart

Can I somehow avoid it? Is there a better practice to improve my developer experience?

Comment: Deeply nesting is common in flutter and quite normal. Though indentation usually is only 2 spaces, not what is done in the example. That looks terrible

Comment: Ivo Bekers, when I see the such deep nesting, I remember my old experience with callback hell in JS before Promises were released.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most important thing working with flutter and having a nice development experience is to have a cristal clear structure. There are plenty structures you can follow, but the way flutter works is a lot of nesting. Me for example in bigger projects I'm following this concept:

```
- [folder] lib
    - [folder] models
    - [folder] apis
    - [folder] bloc (or any other state management / business logic pattern)
    - [folder] pages
        - [folder] page 1
        - [folder] page 2
        - [folder] page 3
            - pageview.dart
            - widget 1.dart
            - widget 2.dart
            - widget 3.dart
    - [folder] widgets (every widget which is used appwide)
    - main.dart
```

Im feeling comfortable with this. I have clea places for api, models, business logic, pages and since you can refactor your code and create widgets out of it, my pages are smaller than what you are seeing on your github example. I can also find widgets fast which are used on more than one place in my app.

Finding a good structure and create a lot widgets makes it easy to understand your code later on. I can ofcourse only talk for myself, for me its very comfortable.

Comment: I am not sure you got my question correcrly, I've provided an example with an nesting issue of code of a widget, not a project structure.

Comment: Hey yeah, i just wanted to extend it a little bit, because the structure is also really important for readability. like you anwered in the below comment where you are showing the example with react, you can do the exact same by refactoring widgets like I explained in my answer. Check this out: https://www.raywenderlich.com/10126984-creating-reusable-custom-widgets-in-flutter here you can go threw the tutorial to create custom widgets to reduce the nesting

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that most of the places, we do some kind of nesting whether it is HTML, Android XML or so on. So manageable nesting is allowed in most of the places.

Though I have seen there are some unnecessary nesting done on your provided example.

For e.g.

```html
 void updateListView() {

        final Future<Database> dbFuture = databaseHelper.initializeDatabase();
        dbFuture.then((database) {

            Future<List<Note>> noteListFuture = databaseHelper.getNoteList();
            noteListFuture.then((noteList) {
                setState(() {
                  this.noteList = noteList;
                  this.count = noteList.length;
                });
            });
        });
  }
```

Here we could have avoided the above nesting using `await` keyword something like below

```html
void updateListView() {
    // I don't know why is it even there but if it is required then it should be done in
    // below way which is commented out
    // final Database database = await databaseHelper.initializeDatabase(); 
    List<Note> noteList = await databaseHelper.getNoteList();
    setState(() {
      this.noteList = noteList;
      this.count = noteList.length;
    });
}
```

> And the above code should be properly linted to be readable lol

Comment: What's about getNoteListView method in the example? Nesting looks so weird.

Comment: I think that is alright. It looks bad and not that readable because this code is not formatted properly. Once it is formatted the code will look somewhat meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

It is an important part of the declarative way flutter works. So no, IMHO, you cannot avoid nesting. And if you could, it would be a workaround, circumventing the basic concepts of flutter..
Just use flutter the way it's intended.. As i said: just my humble opinion

Comment: Yeah, but Could I somehow separate at least properties and widget declarations?

For example similar to React:

```
<Button props={ButtonProps}>
   <Icon props={IconProps} />
</Button>
```